# LINQ Query for Filter Result

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, ado.net

Experts,

I have a datatable with two columns:

1) One is Decimal
2) One is String

I write my filter query like:

```
var iFilterResult = from c in dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
                                    where c.Field<string>("ACM_ACCOUNT_CODE").Contains(txtFindPrePaidExpenses.Text)
                                    && c.Field<string>("ACM_ACCOUNT_DESC").Contains(txtFindPrePaidExpenses.Text)
                                    select new
                                    {
                                        ACM_ACCOUNT_CODE = c.Field<string>("ACM_ACCOUNT_CODE"),
                                        ACM_ACCOUNT_DESC = c.Field<string>(" ACM_ACCOUNT_DESC")
                                    };
                gvSearchAccountGL.DataSource = iFilterResult;
                gvSearchAccountGL.DataBind();  "
```

Here `dataTable1` is Datatable Having Column

`ACM_ACCOUNT_CODE` of decimal type
`ACM_ACCOUNT_DESC` of string type.

use like Query for filter.

But it is not working

Comment: How is it "not working"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to use ACM_ACCOUNT_CODE as a string field - but you've said it's a decimal field.

It's not clear why you'd expect a decimal field to contain the same value as the description field. If you *really* want this, you could use:

```
c.Field<decimal>("ACM_ACCOUNT_CODE")
 .ToString()
 .Contains(txtFindPrePaidExpenses.Text)
```

... but I suspect you should rethink what the query is trying to do.

Comment: Actually I Fill Datable from database after that all filtration are done from datable without hit database.

Comment: @Dinesh: Yes, I was talking about your *LINQ* query.